# Regex to match a substring and an URL from string iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have a string that contains some text and urls. I tried to get matching urls and text like following,

```
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)([(H)|(h)]ttp?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?)", concatName];
```

But this giving me a wrong result. What is wrong with this pattern?

Comment: You can use `NSDataDetector` to match urls

Comment: what about the substring in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString * Check_Url = @"www.google.com";
NSDataDetector * dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult * firstMatch = [dataDetector firstMatchInString:mail options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [Check_Url length])];
BOOL result = [firstMatch.URL isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]] && [firstMatch.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"Your_URL"];
```

Try this. May be it helps you Or feel free ?